# failed to resolve (add) cameraX in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camerax

my editor thinks the environment is ok, the picture as follows
i have added `google()  mavenCentral()` in settings.gradle

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.camera:camera-core:1.1.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In gradle repositories add google `repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() }`

Answer (score 0):

i installed android studio in virtual machine and it works well.
i reinstalled it(deleated .android and .gradle),but it didn't work at all
i don't know how to solve the problem unless change a new computer

Comment: Consider containing the discussion in the comment thread. Post an answer if you have permanent resolution to the issue.